# GET and POST requests to MongoDB not working, Thunder Client processing forever

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, prisma, next.js13

i have a project where i'm making a CRUD application using nextjs13, prisma and mongoDB.

When i load the /dashboard page, it is supposed to pull some data from my base and display it on screen. Unfortunately, it shows some data from one of my collections in mongo db, but not the one i want it to. for conext, i have a database called test with collections Account, User, Post and Program. Account an user are working, Post is the collection where the data shown on screen is situated, Program is the collection where i want it to be taken from.

When i run the requests, both get and post in thinder client, it just says "processing" forever and never gives me an answer.

this is the relevant code:
app/(site)/page.jsx:

```
import AddPost from '../../components/AddPost'
import SignOutButton from '../../components/SignOutButton'
import { getSession, getServerSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import PostList from '../../components/PostList'

async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/posts');

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }

  return res.json();
}

const Dashboard = async() => {

  const posts = await getData()



  return (
    <div>
      <div className="min-h-screen">
        <div className="max-w-4xl mx-auto mt-4">
          <div className="my-5 flex flex-col gap-4">
            <div className="text-2xl font-bold">
              <h1>Admin panel</h1>
            </div>
            
            <AddPost />
            <PostList posts={posts} />
            <SignOutButton />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

app/components/AddPost.jsx:

```
'use client'

import React from 'react'
import Modal from './Modal'
import { useState } from 'react' 
import axios from 'axios'

const AddPost = () => {

  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false)
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({})

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post('/api/posts', inputs).then(res =>{
      console.log(res)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    }).finally(() => {
      setInputs({})
      setModalOpen(false)
    })
  }

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    setInputs(prevState => ({...prevState, [name]: value}))
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setModalOpen(true)} className='bg-blue-700 text-white p-3 cursor-pointer'>Add new post</button>

      <Modal modalOpen={modalOpen} setModalOpen={setModalOpen}>
        <form className='w-full' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <h1 className='text-2xl pb-3'>Add new post</h1>
      
          <input 
            type='text'
            placeholder='Title'
            name='title'
            className='w-full p-2'
            value={inputs.title || ""}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />

          <input 
            type='text'
            placeholder='Description'
            name='description'
            className='w-full p-2 my-5'
            value={inputs.description || ""}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />

          <button type="submit" className='bg-blue-700 text-white px-5 py-2'>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AddPost
```

app/components/PostList.jsx

```
    import React from 'react'
    import Post from './Post'
    
    
    const PostList = ({posts}) => {
        
    
      return (
        <ul>
          {
            posts.map( post => (
                <Post key = {post.id} post={post} />
            ))
          }
          
        </ul>
      )
    }
    
    export default PostList

app/components/Post.jsx:

    import React from 'react'

const Post = ({post}) => {
  return (
    <li className = 'p-3 my-5 bg-slate-200' key={post.id}>
        <h1 className='text-2xl font-bold'>{post.title}</h1>
        <p>{post.description}</p>
        <p>{post.price}</p>
        <p>{post.bg_photo}</p>
        <p>{post.edu_logo}</p>
    </li>
  )
}

export default Post
```

app/components/Modal.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'

const Modal = ({children, modalOpen, setModalOpen}) => {
  return (
    <>
        {modalOpen &&(
            <div className="bg-black/50 fixed inset-0">
            <div className="flex justify-center items-center h-full">
                <div className="flex flex-col items-end bg-slate-300 2-1/2 p-5">
                    <button className="text-2xl mb-3">
                        &items;
                    </button>
    
                    {children}
                </div>
            </div>
          
        </div>
        )}
    </>
  )
}

export default Modal
```

app/libs/prismadb.jsx:

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const client = globalThis.prisma || new PrismaClient();
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") globalThis.prisma = client;

export default client;
```

root/prisma/schema.prisma:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id             String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name       String?
  email          String?   @unique
  emailVerified  DateTime?
  image          String?
  hashedPassword String?
  createdAt      DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt      DateTime  @updatedAt

  accounts Account[]
}

model Account {
  id                String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  userId            String  @db.ObjectId
  type              String
  provider          String
  providerAccountId String
  refresh_token     String? @db.String
  access_token      String? @db.String
  expires_at        Int?
  token_type        String?
  scope             String?
  id_token          String? @db.String
  session_state     String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)


  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])


}

model Program{
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title String?
  description String?
  price String?
  bg_photo String?
  edu_logo String?
```

}

app/api/posts/route.jsx:

```
import prisma from "../../libs/prismadb"
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"

export const POST = async (request) => {
    try {
        const body = await request.json()
        const {title,description,price,bg_photo,edu_logo} = body
        const newPost = await prisma.post.create({
            data:{
                
                title,
                description,
                price,
                bg_photo,
                edu_logo
            }
        })

        return NextResponse.json(newPost)
    }catch(err){
        return NextResponse.json({ message: "POST Error", error: err }, { status: 500 });
    }
}

export const GET = async () => {
    try {
        
        const posts = await prisma.post.findMany()

        return NextResponse.json(posts)
    }catch(err){
        return NextResponse.json({message: "GET Error", err}, {status:500})
    }
}
```

app/posts/[id]/route.jsx:

```
import prisma from "../../../libs/prismadb"
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"

export const GET = async (request,{ params }) => {
    try {
        
        const { id } = params
        const post = await prisma.post.findUnique({
            where:{
                id
            }
        })

        if(!post){
            return NextResponse.json(
                {message: "Post not found", err},
                {status: 404}
            )
        }

        return NextResponse.json(post)
    }catch(err){
        return NextResponse.json({message: "GET Error", err}, {status:500})
    }
}

export const DELETE = async (request,{ params }) => {
    try {
        
        const { id } = params
        
        await prisma.post.delete({
            where:{
                id
            }
        })

        return NextResponse.json("Post has been deleted.")
    }catch(err){
        return NextResponse.json({message: "DELETE Error", err}, {status:500})
    }
}

export const PATCH = async (request, { params }) => {
    try {
        const body = await request.json()
        const {title,description,price,bg_photo,edu_logo} = body
        const { id } = params
        
        const updatePost = await prisma.post.update({
            where:{
                id
            },
            data: {
                title,
                description,
                price,
                bg_photo,
                edu_logo
            }
        })

        if(!updatePost){
            return NextResponse.json(
                {message: "Post not found", err},
                {status: 404}
            )
        }

        return NextResponse.json(updatePost)
    }catch(err){
        return NextResponse.json({message: "Update Error", err}, {status:500})
    }
}
```

For context, i know it's old data sowing because when i update my database from mongodb console it doesnt fetch the new data when i rerun mu localhost server. I don't know why, because it was working a couple of days ago. Also, the model Program in the schema.prisma used to be model Post with title, desc, date created and dateupdated and nothing else, which is what i see in the frontend.

Any suggestions?